# Iwasawa Decomposition $SL_n(\Bbb{R})$ Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, matrix-decomposition

A special case of the Iwasawa Decomposition for matrices is the following: Let $G=SL_n(\Bbb{R})$, $K=$ real unitary matrices, $U=$ upper triangular matrices with $1$'s on the diagonal (called *unipotent*), and $A=$ diagonal matrices with positive elements ($0$ everywhere else). Then, the product map $U\times{A}\times{K}\rightarrow{G}$ given by $(u,a,k)\mapsto{uak}$ is a bijection.

I am looking at the proof of this in Serge Lang's Undergraduate Algebra, Section 6 Chapter 4 pg 246, however, I need some help in understanding the beginning of the proof:

"Let $e_1,..,e_n$ be the standard vertical unit vectors of $\Bbb{R^n}$. Let $g=(g_{ij})\in{G}$. Then we have $ge_i=\begin{pmatrix} g_{1i}  \\ \vdots \\ g_{ni} \end{pmatrix}=g^{(i)}=\sum_{q=1}^n g_{qi}e_q$. There exists an upper triangular matrix $B=(b_{ij})$, so with $b_{ij}=0$ if $i>j$ such that $b_{11}g^{(1)}=e'_1$,..........,$b_{1j}g^{(1)}+b_{2j}g^{(2)}+...+b_{jj}g^{(j)}=e'_j$,..............,  $b_{1n}g^{(1)}+b_{2n}g^{(2)}+...+b_{nn}g^{(n)}=e'_n$, such that the diagonal elements are positive, that is $b_{11},...,b_{nn}>0$, and such that the vectors $e'_1,...,e'_n$ are mutually perpendicular unit vectors. Getting such a matrix B is merely applying the usual Gram Schmidt orthogonalisation process, subtracting a linear combination of previous vectors to get orthogonality, and then dividing by the norms to get unit vectors."

My problem here is understanding the matrix $B$ and how it is obtained. Having studied the Gram Schmidt Orthogonalisation process in a linear algebra course, I simply learnt it as a way to construct an orthogonal (orthonormal by diving by norms) basis for a finite dimensional inner product space (in this case $\Bbb{R}$) given any basis. Could someone please explain how Lang then guarantees the existence of this matrix $B$.

Thank you.

ADDITIONAL (carrying on where Lang's proof left off): Let $gB=k\in{K}$. Then $ke_i=e'_i$, so the columns of $k$ are orthonormal, so $k$ is real unitary, and $g=kB^{-1}$. Then $g^{-1}=Bk^{-1}$ and $B=au$, where $a$ is the diagonal matrix with $a_i=b_{ii}$ and $u$ is unipotent, $u=a^{-1}B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gram Schmidt is as follows, depicted visually 
[image]

such that

$$a_{1} = r_{11} q_{1} \\a_{2} = r_{12}q_{1} + r_{22}q_{2}\\ a_{3}= r_{13}q_{1} +r_{23}q_{2} + r_{33} q_{3} \\ \vdots \\ a_{n} = r_{1n} q_{1} + r_{2n}q_{2} + \cdots + r_{nn} q_{n} $$

giving

$$A = \hat{Q}\hat{R} $$

The matrix $B$ appears to be the matrix $R$.

How it is found

$$ q_{1} = \frac{a_{1}}{r_{11}}\\ q_{2} = \frac{a_{2}-r_{12}q_{1}}{r_{22}}\\q_{3}  = \frac{a_{3}-r_{13}q_{1}-r_{23}q_{2}}{r_{33}}\\ \vdots \\ q_{n} = \frac{a_{n} - \sum_{i=1}^{n} r_{in}q_{i}}{r_{nn}}$$

where

$$ |r_{ij} | = q_{i}^{*}a_{j} \\
 | r_{jj}| = \| a_{j} = \sum_{i=1}^{j-1} r_{ij}q_{i}\|_{2}$$

seen here
[image]

Giving your $B$ from that

Comment: So this is just a reference to the QR decomposition, which uses the Gram-Schmidt process

Comment: The QR decomposition is Gram-Schmidt. It decomposes a matrix into an orthogonal matrix and an upper triangular matrix of coefficients.  Your question was constructing the matrix B which was an upper triangular matrix with vectors that $e_{1}, e_{2}, \cdots, e_{n}$ that are orthogonal...these $q_{1}, q_{2}, \cdots q_{n} $ I would imagine...you can't construct the orthogonal vectors without the coefficients...you're subtracting them off.

Comment: Lang then states that one can write $B=au$, where $a$ is the diagonal matrix with $a_i=b_{ii}$ and $u$ is unipotent, $u=a^{-1}B$. I understand why $u$ is thus unipotent, but could you please explain how he guarantees $B=au$. Thank you

Comment: This is after having stated, $gB=k$, where $k$ is unitary , so $g=kB^{-1}$, so $g^{-1}=Bk^{-1}$ (I understand this) and (thus?) $B=au$.

Comment: @Daniele1234 I'll have to look at Langs book

Comment: I continued the proof above in my answer up to this point if that helps...

Comment: I feel like what the book is saying and you've continued with makes sense.

Comment: It is Lang who states that $B=au$, I'm just trying to understand why $B$ has this decomposition...

Comment: Oh, it is a pivot. There is another decomposition of gram schmidt I believe called the QR factorization with pivots. http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node42.html . pivot matrix is diagonal matrix.

Comment: Ah thank you. Last question I promise! Why does it follow that $a$ has positive diagonal elements, and not negative (this is crucial for proving uniqueness of the decomposition)

Comment: Will have to think about that..didn't cover this..

Comment: Perhaps, in general, in a QR decomposition one can always ensure that the diagonal elements of R are positive?

Comment: There is small spot for unique and existence in the Trefethen book I am reading. It's on page 52. It was my belief from lectures that the decompositions were unique to a constant multiple scaling of the columns. it has to do with the rank of the matrix.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that this proof does not rely at all on the fact that $g$ has determinant $1$, only that its determinant is non-zero, so doesn't this proof hold for all matrices in the general linear group?

Comment: Perhaps this determinant 1 arises in the uniqueness?

Comment: well you can show that the determinant is one from the following I believe..
$ G  = U \cdot A \cdot K$ , $det(G) = det(U A K ) = det(U) det(A)det(K) = $
u is a diagonal matrix with ones on the diagonal. $det(U) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} u_{ii} = 1 $  $ det(A) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} a_{ii}  > 0 $  determinant of unitary matrix k is 1..

Comment: But where in Lang's proof does the fact that $g$ has determinant 1 ever come into play?

Comment: It says it comes from $SL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: I understand, but there is nowhere in the proof that makes use of this fact thus making it redundant no? It appears that this decomposition would work for all matrices with nonzero determinant..

Comment: is it the relationship you make at the end $a_{i} = b_{ii} $  $a_{i} = 1$ no?

Comment: It is never stated that $a_i=1$, only that $a_i=b_{ii}$ by the (still rather mysterious!) decomposition $B=au$... perhaps I should make a full post about this decomposition as there are still so many questions from $B=au$, to why determinant 1 only, to showing uniqueness', etc.

Comment: Perhaps later I can send you the pages of the proof directly as a photo from Lang's book (either email, new stackexchange post with picture, etc.)

Comment: Yes, its a lot to think about.

Comment: my email is ryhowe@gmail.com if you want to send the book

Comment: Thanks man for the effort you're putting into this problem really appreciated :) I'm about to shortly put a Stackexchange post with pictures from the book so hopefully it will be more clear

Comment: Here is the link to the post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2872455/iwasawa-matrix-decomposition-proof     but I can't find a way to make the pictures smaller on screen!