# Iwasawa Matrix Decomposition Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, linear-groups

Iwasawa Decomposition (special case): Let $G=SL_n(\Bbb{R})$, $K=$ real unitary matrices, $U=$ upper triangular matrices with $1$'s on the diagonal (called *unipotent*), and $A=$ diagonal matrices with positive elements ($0$ everywhere else). Then, the product map $U\times{A}\times{K}\rightarrow{G}$ given by $(u,a,k)\mapsto{uak}$ is a bijection.

Here is the proof by Serge Lang in his book Undergraduate Algebra Section 6 Chapter 4 pg 246 (Read below picture for question(s) please :)

[image: pg1 of proof]

[image: pg2 of proof]

I have a few questions about this proof (understand it roughly as a whole):

1) How does one get that $B=au$, following $g^{-1}=Bk^{-1}$?

2) Why does it follow that A has positive diagonal elements - that is $a_i=b_{ii}>0$? (My guess is that the QR decomposition guarantees this for R and note $B=R$)

3) I can't see any point in the proof where Lang makes a reference to the fact that $g$ has determinant $1$, in fact it seems that $g$ could have any non-zero determinant, hence $g\in{GL_n(\Bbb{R})}$. Why is this not so?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diagonal entries of $B$ are positive, because they are the lengths of the vectors in Gram-Schmidt. To write $B=au$, I will do it in $2\times 2$ so that you see what happens:
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix} b_{11} & b_{12} \\ 0& b_{22}\end{bmatrix} 
=\begin{bmatrix} b_{11} &0 \\ 0& b_{22} \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 1&b_{12}/b_{11}\\ 0&1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
As for the determinant, the way the decomposition is phrased it is not restricted to the case $\det g=1$, since $a$ is allowed arbitrary diagonal entries so the determinant can be arbitrary. Note that $\det u=1$, $\det k=\pm1$, so $$\det g=\pm\det a.$$

Comment: Thank you for this. So this decomposition is in fact for $GL_n(\Bbb{R})$ as $g$ can be any non-zero determinant?

Comment: Yes. $ \ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: Why would Lang then so heavily restrict himself to special linear when he could use the much more general General Linear group - perhaps an aesthetic thing?

Comment: I have no idea. To my taste, the whole writing of the proof is horrible.

Comment: No wonder I was confused! Thank you for your input.